# Finding the amount of error with a multiple regression formula that is determining stock returns

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, standard-error, regression-coefficients, neweywest

I'm brand new to statistics and I'm using C# and Math.Net to perform multiple regression on a formula with 3 inputs and 1 output. I was told that finding an rsquared value isn't recommended for a regression formula involving stocks but I don't know why exactly.

Here is some example code I am using:

```
Vector<double> highRiskCoefficient = MultipleRegression.QR(
                                        Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfColumnArrays(highRiskShortRatingList.ToArray(), highRiskMediumRatingList.ToArray(), highRiskLongRatingList.ToArray()),
                                        Vector<double>.Build.Dense(highRiskWeekReturnList.ToArray()));

                highRiskShortCoefficient = Convert.ToDecimal(highRiskCoefficient[0]);
                highRiskMediumCoefficient = Convert.ToDecimal(highRiskCoefficient[1]);
                highRiskLongCoefficient = Convert.ToDecimal(highRiskCoefficient[2]);
                highRiskRSquared = calc.calculateRSquared(highRiskWeekReturnList, highRiskShortRatingList, highRiskShortCoefficient, highRiskMediumRatingList,
                    highRiskMediumCoefficient, highRiskLongRatingList, highRiskLongCoefficient);
```

I heard about the newey-west formula found at this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newey%E2%80%93West_estimator

I can't find an explanation for this formula and I have no idea what the symbols mean. Is this what I want for my situation? If so, can anyone please dumb down what I should to incorporate this formula? Or if this isn't the right way to go, is there something you would recommend that I try?